# How to split a string using a lookahead assertion with changing delimiters

Tags: java, regex, split, regex-lookarounds

Given that my english got really rusty lately, I shall put it short.
What I want to do, is to split a string into set of substrings keeping the delimiters as parts of the respective substrings. Of course, it wouldn’t be anything difficult, if it wasn’t for the fact, that the delimiters may vary. Say I have a string akin to:

> [ffd][ulg][zff] = 1 = ... = 2 = ... [bdt] = 3 = ... [abc][dfg][urc][ttr] = 4 = ...

and I want to split it into following substrings:

> [ffd][ulg][zff] = 1 = ...
>
> = 2 = ...
>
> [bdt] = 3 = ...
>
> [abc][dfg][urc][ttr] = 4 = ...

Note, that the „= number =” sequence has to be always there (and is a basic delimiter), but it may (or may not) be preceded by varying number of \[\w{3}\] groups.

So far, I have toyed with expressions like:

> ?=((\[\w{3}\])+\s= \d\{3} =)

or

> ?=((\[\w{3}\])*\s= \d\{3} =)

The first one returns: [ffd], [uld], [zff] = 1 = …, [bdt] = 3 =, [abc], [dfg], [urc], [ttr] = 4 = ... as separate strings. Unsurprisingly it has a problem with treating [\w{3}] clusters as one and interprets “= 2 = …” as a part of “[zff] = 1 =  …” substring. The other one simply interprets each [\w{3}] and each “= number = …” sequence  as separate strings. Additionally I have tried to embed OR clause as an argument of the split method, i.e.:

> (?=((\[\w{3}\])+\s= \d\{3} =|= \d\{3} =))

but the effect was the same as in the second case.

Comment: Okay, what have you tried? What's the problem with the code/regex you have so far?

Comment: `...` is actual content or a placeholder for more `[asd][cxg]`?

Comment: @zapl the ellipses stand for any given textual content

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to split with a lookbehind assertion?:

```
(?<== [0-9]{1,1000} =)
```

or use find with:

```
\\[.*?(?:= [0-9]+ =|$)
```

Comment: Look behinds must be of fixed length. Try your look behind in code/tester

Comment: @Bohemian: No, in Java you are allowed to use variable length lookbehinds if the length is limited. You can try it with regexplanet.com

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I’m afraid lookbehinds won’t do the trick. They return aforementioned substrings with delimiters cut out. As for the find, it returns: [ffd][ulg][zff] = 1 = ... , [bdt] = 3 = ...  and 
[abc][dfg][urc][ttr] = 4 = ... as it should, so you’re close, but it fails to catch the unpreceded “= number =" clauses.

Comment: @AstragalFrigide: It indeed fails to find an "unpreceded number clause", but it's not important since in this case the item can only be the first item, and in this case the split method will do the job by separating it from the others.

Comment: @AstragalFrigide: are in your question `...` literal `...`? if this answer is no, what is the max length of `...`?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Nay, after running split with (?=\\[.*?(?:= [0-9]+ =|$)) - if such was your intention - I got: "[ffd]", "[ulg]", "[zff] = 1 = ... = 2 = ...", "[bdt] = 3 = ...", "[abc]", "[dfg]", "[urc]" and "[ttr] = 4 = ..." :( And "..." can be any text - at least theoretically - of any length.